# Unable to remove file with os.remove()

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Just trying File IO operations.
The os.remove() function is unable to delete the file
Code below

```
file=open("test.txt","r+")
text=file.read()
print(text)
file.close()
os.remove("test.txt")
```

---

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-122dc088faef> in <module>
      4 file.close()
      5 #youcantdeleteifyoudontcloseit
----> 6 os.remove("test.txt")

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'test.txt'
```

Comment: Is the file open in `notepad.exe` or another editor?

Comment: No..Not open anywhere

Answer (score 1):

> Not open anywhere

The error message unequivocally indicates that the file is open somewhere. Even for Windows there are tools available which can find the process having the file open, such as the Sysinternals Process Explorer.